# How to use existing libraries made by google?

Tags: android

I want to import **libcore** package which is not present by default in android studio 2.3.3. **compile 'org.robovm:robovm-rt:+'** in **build.gradle** does not work, it gives *Failed to resolve* error. Is there any other option besides downloading its jar.

I want to use InflatorInputStream.java file in my app with some modification in it. I want to get total bytes read in inputstream (not outputstream which is returned by in.read())

In build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'android-libcore', version: '4.3_r2.robolectric-0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

In Messages tab:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\pebble\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\src\main\java\pebble\test\InflaterInputStream.java
Error:(28, 26) error: package libcore.io does not exist
Error:(107, 34) error: cannot find symbol class RAFStream
Error:(139, 15) error: cannot find symbol method checkOffsetAndCount(int,int,int)
Error:(167, 22) error: cannot find symbol class DataFormatException
Error:(186, 20) error: cannot find symbol class RAFStream
Error:(186, 44) error: cannot find symbol class RAFStream
Error:(187, 26) error: illegal start of type
Error:(213, 16) error: cannot find symbol variable Streams
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 52.353 secs
Information:9 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this just add the below file in your dependencies of your build.gradle (Module:app) file ,

```
 implementation group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'android-libcore', version: '4.3_r2.robolectric-0'
```

or

**Updated:::**

```
compile group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'android-libcore', version: '4.3_r2.robolectric-0'
```

or use this

```
compile 'org.robolectric:android-libcore:4.3_r2.robolectric-0'
```

You can also use compile in place of implementation but it will be deprecated at the end of 2018 so better **use implementation in place of compile** for future use.

Also you can eventually get all related third party library or main library on maven repository here is the link,

https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: it gives error: **gradle dsl not found: implementation().** When i replace **implementation** with **compile**, gradle file does not give error but **import libcore.io** gives error.

Comment: try to use compile for now and if error is cohwing please post the error in your question

Comment: I used compile, there is no build(gradle) error but in  java file when i type **import libcore.io.Streams;** it gives error **Cannot resolve symbol 'libcore'**

Comment: i downloaded robovm-rt-0.0.14.jar and now i get error on **ZipFile.RAFStream**. I saw **RAFStream** class inside robovm but i think android is using default java package instead from robovm.jar. How can i tell android to use java from specfic jar?